# R, how to narrow down a histogram domain?

Tags: r, histogram

I've been working with R language, I've created a histogram from a data file this way:

> a <- read.table("_datafile.txt");
>
> b <- table(a);
>
> c <- as.numeric(names(b));
>
> hist(c, 100);

This is the result, in the attached image:

[Histogram http://www.imagehost.it/dm/FILK/istogrammaBis.png](http://www.imagehost.it/dm/FILK/istogrammaBis.png)

My problem is that I'd like to exclude the 1rst bar of the histogram.

D'you know the R command to do it?

Thanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hist` uses 'Sturges' breaks (equal spaced intervals of number determined by `nclass.Sturges`) as the default break locations, but you are over-riding that. The second break value would be

seq( min(x), max(x), by= diff(range(x))/10 )[2]

So:

```
hist(c[ c >= seq( min(c), max(c), by= diff(range(c))/10 )[2], 9 ] )
```

I reduced the number of bins to keep the categories the same. If you want to see the formula for the number of breaks in the default just type:

```
nclass.Sturges
```

It's not uncommon to find people puzzled by the behavior of `hist` with small numbers of equally spaced observations. because the result looks irregular. Try:

```
hist(0:8)
```

Comment: Thanx, but in your example what x stands for? Is it my c?

Comment: Right. Will fix. (Although "c" is a very bad choice of variable name.)

Comment: Thanks to your answer, I realized one could also manipulate the breaks to tweak a histogram, without removing data, e.g. hist(x, breaks=seq(min(x),max(x),by=1 ), which is always good to know.

Answer (score 0):

The [HistogramTools](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/HistogramTools/) package on CRAN provides a number of simple helper functions to remove bins from a histogram or narrow down the histogram domain.  See, for example, the `SubsetHistogram` and `TrimHistogram` functions.

Suppose for example we have this initial histogram:

```
hist.1 <- hist(runif(100,min=2,max=4), breaks=seq(0,6,by=.2), plot=FALSE)
```

[image]

We can trim off the empty buckets with `TrimHistogram` like this:

```
hist.trimmed <- TrimHistogram(hist.1)
```

[image]

We can further specify maximum or minimum breakpoints to exclude bins at the left or right of the histogram (narrow the domain in the original posters terminology) with the `SubsetHistogram` function like this:

```
plot(SubsetHistogram(hist.trimmed, 2.2))
```

[image]